# Why isn't Windows 2008 Service Pack 2 appearing in Windows Update?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I've got a Windows 2008 (Service Pack 1, obviously) PC as my workstation. Windows 2008 Service Pack 2 has been out for a while now. Why am I not being offered it as an option in Windows Update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you gone through this [checklist](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948343)?

*(MS KB 948343: Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008 service packs are not available for installation through Windows Update)*

Comment: Looked like it was Live Messenger; I just downloaded and installed the SP directly. That worked fine (on the second attempt).